# .bat - Regex Rename?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I cant understand how exactly we use reges in batch files.

I simple need to replace `vm_[^_]*_` with nothing on ONLY `.txt` files in subfolders of lets say C:/ProjectFiles/

The file names look like:
`vm_dsr_ads_fire.txt`
`vm_m1911_idle.txt`

I need them to end up with the file names:
`ads_fire.txt`
`idle.txt`

How do I do this?

Comment: As I said pure batch has no regex capabiliies, you need either external tools or a different scripting language. For the renamingI can recommend [jren.bat from dbenham](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081&hilit=jren) which is a batch/jscript hybrid. You just have to check for the exact regex syntax

Comment: @LotPings findstr has regex capabilities, just not replace.

Comment: sed(third party),  and a "bouncing off the command prompt" technique would be simple and flexible.. moreso than a 'for'.

Comment: @barlop Thanks, I'm aware of the very limited RegEx capabilities of findstr. Nevertheless findstr is an indispensable tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the `help for` and exercising?

Lets get serious, you don't need a regex here (if so then you would be better off using vbscript or Powershell)

This batch generates a `DoRename.cmd` you may revise and execute afterwards. CHange `Basefld` to fit your env.

```
@Echo off
Set Basefld=Q:\Test
Pushd %Basefld% ||(Echo can't cd to %Basefld%&Pause&Exit /B 1)
> DoRename.cmd (
For /F "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S "vm_*_*.txt"'
  ) DO For /F "tokens=1,2* Delims=_" %%B in ('Echo:%%~nxA'
    ) Do Echo Ren "%%~A" "%%D"
)
start "" Notepad.exe DoRename.cmd
```

This second batch has no unneccessary seatbelts and will immediately rename files in current dir and subdirs.

```
@Echo off
For /F "Delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/S "vm_*_*.txt"'
  ) DO For /F "tokens=1,2* Delims=_" %%B in ('Echo:%%~nxA'
    ) Do Ren "%%~A" "%%D"
```

The first for walks the tree for fhe files, 
the second parses the filename and extension. 
delims=_ splits the name into tokens. 
token1 aka %%B being ´vm´ 
token2 %%C the text between the first 2 underscores 
and token3 `*` %%D the rest of the name including the .ext .

Comment: Please get rid of all of these "Set" and checks to see if they can CD - They arent needed for me - A simple CD Q:\Test will suffice.

Comment: Im a bit confused what its actually doing doe. I simply want code to do regex.

Comment: Output: `Ren "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III\xanim_export\custom\weapons\an94\vm_an94_ads_down.XANIM_BIN" "export\custom\weapons\an94\vm")` It doesnt actually rename .

Comment: Sorry for that. Edited the batch, try again. The first for walks the tree for fhe files, the second parses the (now) only the filename and extension. delims=_ splits the name into tokens. token1 aka %%B being ´vm´ token2 %%C the text between the first 2 underscores and %%D the rest of the name. I have to correct the batch for this. 1minute

Comment: Ok with the edit in the Output its echoing the correct values (From what it seems) but its not actually renaming the files.

EDIT: My bad - Forgot to remove "Echo" before "Ren".

Comment: Really quick - How would I remove something like: `an94_` from `an94_viewmodel_up`? In regex id just do `[^_]*_` which removes everything before and including the first _.

Comment: In a similar way. Dir an64_* then tokens=1,* and use %%B

Comment: That should have been %%C

Comment: Why don't you just provide a batch file instead of generating one on the fly? That would be much less confusing for any readers.

Comment: @DavidPostill Agreed, but this allows to review and in case of disaster you might roll back

Comment: @LotPings incorrect just having the section of code inside of `> DoRename.cmd` will show the result (AND WORK) but wont actually make the changes unless you remove the "Echo" bit from `Do Echo Ren` - If you keep it it just shows the changes that would be made (Kind of)

Comment: It's much simpler (and more understandable) just to `echo` the `ren` command and remove the `echo` when you are happy with it. The rest is just fluff.

Comment: The file mask should include two underscores as `vm_*_*.txt` so as not to incorrectly rename files that don't meet the correct pattern.